# How can I choose browser and then choose my specific URL from user

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Automation testing using Selenium. That's why, I'm facing issue regarding to taking browser and the URL from user input . Like, when my code is executed, first user input is choosen as your organisation and second is choosen as your URL like Google,Facebook etc.

```
public class Pages {


private enum Organization {
    Firefox, Chrom 
}
 static Organization obj;
private static Pages Chrom;
private static Scanner reader;
private static Scanner reader_1;
public static void main(String[]args)  throws InterruptedException {

    char ch;
    String org;
do
{

System.out.println("");
reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
System.out.println("Please Enter The Browser Name :");
 org = reader.nextLine();
obj=Organization.valueOf(org);
switch(obj)
{
 case Firefox:
     Pages.Firefoxdriver();
     break;
 case Chrom: 
     Pages.Chromedriver();
     break;
     default:
        System.out.println("You Have Selected Wrong Browser ");
}
reader_1 = new Scanner(System.in);  
System.out.println("Please a key followed by ENTER: \n ");
 ch = reader_1.next().charAt(0);

} while (ch != 'q');
}

public static void Firefoxdriver(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://qa-0.ls.vu");
}

public static void Chromedriver(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://qa-0.ls.vu");

}

public void IEdriver(){
    File file =new File("C:/Users/mkv/workspace/ServerDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driverIE=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driverIE.navigate().to("http://www.msn.com");



}
}
```

Comment: what will you do by "Choose Your Organization "

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a few issues and reorganized the code. This is a non-typical way to use Selenium. Most scripts don't ask the user what browser they want to use, etc. You are also going to have an issue if they misspell the browser name. I'm hoping (?) that you are just doing this for fun to try out Selenium.

Some of the things that I fixed:

1. You can reuse `reader`.
2. Removed some extra variables, etc.
3. Separated the conversion of the user input to a driver into a function, `getDriver()`, and it returns a `WebDriver` instance that you can reuse.
4. Added IE to the `enum` and `getDriver()`.
5. Fixed some typos and spelling mistakes.

```
public class Pages
{
    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static Scanner reader;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        char ch;
        do
        {
            System.out.println();
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter the browser name:  ");
            driver = getDriver(reader.nextLine());
            driver.get("http://qa-0.ls.vu");
            System.out.print("Press q to quit followed by ENTER:  ");
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            ch = reader.next().charAt(0);
        } while (ch != 'q');
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver(String browserName)
    {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        Browsers browser = Browsers.valueOf(browserName.toUpperCase());
        switch (browser)
        {
            case FIREFOX:
                System.out.println("Launching Firefox");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case CHROME:
                System.out.println("Launching Chrome");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case IE:
                System.out.println("Launching IE");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Users/mkv/workspace/ServerDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You have selected a browser that isn't available.");
        }

        return driver;
    }

    private enum Browsers
    {
        FIREFOX, CHROME, IE
    }
}
```